# Is there a quick way to change the column's format?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from back limit 2;    
code    report_date total_operating_revenue
000002.XSHE 1989-12-31  15567
000002.XSHE 1990-12-31  23012
```

I want to keep the field `report_date`'s year.
My failed try:

```
update back set report_date = date_format(report_date,'%Y');
select * from back limit 2;
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| code        | report_date | total_operating_revenue |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| 000002.XSHE | 0000-00-00  |                    15567|
| 000002.XSHE | 0000-00-00  |                    23012|
```

Other try:

```
create table new as 
select code,date_format(report_date,'%Y') as report_date,total_operating_revenue from back;
drop table back;
rename table new TO back;
```

I feel it is complicated to use three mysql statements to change the field.
Is there a quick way to change the column's format,not just select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table back modify column report_date char(4);
```

It can change value of field `report_date` such as `1989-12-31` into `1989`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not even be considering storing the year; you already have the full date, from which the year alone can easily be derived.  Just use:

```
SELECT
    code,
    YEAR(report_date) AS report_year,
    total_operating_revenue
FROM back;
```

Note: If you want to use `LIMIT`, you should also be using `ORDER BY`.  I don't know your logic, so I have not used `LIMIT` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to more easily change Database schemes I would recommend using a **GUI** program as they usually make the process way easier.

I would recommend looking into:

**MySQL Workbench** - free - MySQL standard

**HeidiSQL** - free - my favorite as it's light and has a lot of functionality (Windows only, you need Wine for Linux)

**phpMyAdmin** - free  (Uses PHP)

**DataGrip** - paid, InteliJ's DB product.